# Helping getting beginning TryFSharp "Records and option types" Tutorial to work

Tags: f#

I just started studying F# today and have begun working my way through the F# tutorials at http://www.tryfsharp.org/Learn/getting-started#data-structures

In the section above three snippets of code are provided to explain records and option types:

```
type Book =
  { Name: string;
    AuthorName: string;
    Rating: int option;
    ISBN: string }


let unratedEdition = 
   { Name = "Expert F#";
     AuthorName = "Don Syme, Adam Granicz, Antonio Cisternino";
     Rating = None;
     ISBN = "1590598504" }


let printRating book =
match book.Rating with
| Some rating -> 
  printfn "I give this book %d star(s) out of 5!" rating
| None -> printfn "I didn't review this book"
```

I thought that I would be able to apply the printRating like so

```
printRating unratedEdition
```

but I get the following error

```
stdin(63,13): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    FSI_0005.Book    
but here has type
    FSI_0009.Book
```

I'm kinda stuck as to what I am doing wrong here. Any obvious reason that I am totally missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Glad that you figured out how to solve the problem and continue with the tutorials!

I think the automatic loading and evaluation of code snippets in Try F# is a bit confusing. The problem is that you first evaluate first snippet, which defined `Book` and `unratedEdition`. Then, you evaluate second snippet which re-defines `Book` - now, to F# interactive, this is a *different* type hiding the previous definition - together with `printRating` which is a function working on the *new* version of `Book`. When you call:

```
printRating unratedEdition
```

You are calling `printRating` which is a function that takes the *new* `Book` with a value of the *old* `Book` type as an argument (because `unratedEdition` is defined from an earlier interaction; it does not automatically get updated to the new `Book` type and the two types are not compatible).

You can understand this if you evaluate the following three snippets one by one:

```
// Snippet #1: Define first version of the 'Book' type and a value of
// this type named 'unratedEdition'
type Book =
  { Name: string; AuthorName: string; Rating: int option; ISBN: string }

let unratedEdition = 
   { Name = "Expert F#"; Rating = None; ISBN = "1590598504";
     AuthorName = "Don Syme, Adam Granicz, Antonio Cisternino"; }

// Snippet #2: Now, we re-define the 'Book' type (we could also add/remove
// fields to make it actually different, but even without that, this still
// defines a new type hiding the original one). We also define a function that
// operates on the new 'Book' type
type Book =
  { Name: string; AuthorName: string; Rating: int option; ISBN: string }

let printRating book =
  match book.Rating with
  | Some rating -> 
    printfn "I give this book %d star(s) out of 5!" rating
  | None -> printfn "I didn't review this book"

// Snippet #3: This will not work, because we are calling function taking new 
// 'Book' with old 'Book' as an argument. To make this work, you need to evaluate
// one (or the other) definition of Book, then evaluate 'unratedEdition' and then
// 'printRating' (so that the value and function operate on the same 'Book' type)
printRating unratedEdition
```

Note that the editor will complain that the above code is not valid, because it defines `Book` twice, so you can really only get this problem (easily) in Try F# which erases the content of the editor when loading a new snippet

Comment: Wow. thanks!. That really cleared things up! I tried to vote your answer up but I don't have enough rep :(

Comment: It turns out that selecting your solution pushed me over the top into the upvoting possible tier! Yay! Except that now I feel obligated to go back and find all those great solution I wanted to upvote but never could!

Comment: Tomas, I don't know if you had any hand in the design of TryFSharp but I must say I find it very helpful getting started!

Comment: @ChrisTarn I wrote the "Financial Computing" tutorials for Try F#, but I was not involved with the rest :-). But I completely agree - all authors did a really good job and it is a fantastic site to start learning F#!

Comment: I've starting learning F# for use in machine learning applied to finance so I'll definitely be making use of your examples! looking forward to them.

Answer (score 1):

Well I solved my own problem by running all the above code in one shot. i.e. Posting all 3 snippets plus my

```
printRating unratedEdition
```

into the REPL **together** and then hitting RUN. Previously I was using the "load and run" for each individual snippet. I guess it must be some issue with the REPL, or my limited understanding of how a REPL works.

EDIT**
I found myself running into this problem a number of times throughout the tutorial. So, if you have an error, and don't know why, try inserting all the relevant code into the REPL, THEN hit run. This has solved every issue I have run into so far.